# The benefits of using an object relational database such as Oracle/PostrgreSQL vs a regular Relational database?

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms, object-relational-model

I'm curious as to what the major pros/cons are of using an object relational database over a regular relational database are?

In what circumstances is it more practical, and are object relational databases the future?

Comment: This has been asked a few times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800/object-oriented-vs-relational-databases and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571098/moving-to-nosql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an ORM database, you might find it easier to program the interface for fetching data (e.g. no need for developing a special DB software layer), however there will be additional overhead since ORM will generally generate a lot of different methods such as Rails' ActiveRecord find_by_... . Your data underneath will probably still be stored in a relational DB.

With relational DB, the advantage is that it is usually better geared for your specific problem, as your data access layer will only have the minimum neccessary functions for retrieving stuff. The cons are the need to build your own db access layer and having to produce ER diagram for future reference and updates to DB.

Personally, I prefer the relational DB for my projects.

Answer (score 1):

*Object relational* means exactly the same as just plain *relational*. The term "object relational" as used by Oracle and PostGreSQL just means better type support in SQL. It doesn't imply any kind of extension or new feature outside the relational model.